# PySpark Map + Collect vs Collect + Map Pickle Bug

Tags: scikit-learn, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe that I'm trying to turn into a Pandas dataframe after a mapping operation. I can get it to work if I collect via a take operation:

```
a = <scikit-learn object>
b = <scikit-learn object>
my_sdf_list = []
for x in my_sdf.take(20):
  my_sdf_list.append(my_map_func(x, a, b))
```

If I try to collect directly, or convert the mapped dataframe back into a dataframe:

Approach 1

```
my_sdf_list = my_sdf.map(lambda x : my_map_func(x, a, b)).collect()
```

Approach 2

```
pandas_df = my_sdf.map(lambda x : my_map_func(x, a, b)).toDF(my_new_schema).toPandas()
```

then I get the following error:

```
    File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 757, in collect
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2363, in _jrdd
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2283, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 427, in dumps
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 622, in dumps
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 107, in dump
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 193, in save_function
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 241, in save_function_tuple
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 518, in save_reduce
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 518, in save_reduce
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 518, in save_reduce
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 518, in save_reduce
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/apps/python2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 486, in save_string
    self.write(BINSTRING + pack("<i", n) + obj)
struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

The schema for the final row is simple (string, string, string, string, string, double), so I'm assuming the pickle error doesn't have to do with the actual schema. Something to do with passing a scikit-learn object to the data nodes?

Comment: What makes you think that `a` and `b` can be serialized to send to the workers? It would be much more useful if you provide a reproducible example. "scikit-learn object" is not particularly informative.

Comment: Is there a general approach that can be used to serialize an object to send to the workers? Wrap it in something else like a class?